# Error in generating multidimensional array from JSON array

Tags: javascript

I use JavaScript to obtain data from server through PHP.

PHP obtains data from MySQL, encodes it to JSON data and sends it via HTTP protocol to the client - in my case, that is browser.

JavaScript i.e. as shown below picks those values up and renders the chart. Only for testing I'm printing out conversion of the JSONArray to a StringArray which is the output of the PHP.

Any suggestions as to why when my JS code gets to the point below

```
myLogger("myLogger - newObject.dummmysetsJSONArr.entryID" + newObject.dummmysetsJSONArr.entryID);
```

it throws the following error as seen in the console:

```
   uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'entryID' of undefined
```

Here's an example of the DB data converted into JSON:

```
{"dummmysetsJSONArr":[{"entryID":"1","distance":"100","calories":"50"},{"entryID":"2","distance":"200","calories":"100"},{"entryID":"3","distance":"300","calories":"150"},{"entryID":"4","distance":"400","calories":"200"},{"entryID":"5","distance":"500","calories":"250"},{"entryID":"6","distance":"600","calories":"300"}],"success":1}
```

And here's my JS:

```
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

    function drawVisualization() {

      var req = false;
      var jsonarry;

      try {
          // most browsers
          req = new XMLHttpRequest();

          myLogger("myLogger - XMLHttpRequest() created");
      } catch (e){
          // IE
          try{
              req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

              myLogger("myLogger - req = new ActiveXObject(Msxml2.XMLHTTP);");          
          } catch (e) {
              // try an older version
              try{
                  req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                  myLogger("myLogger - req = new ActiveXObject(Microsoft.XMLHTTP);");               
              } catch (e){

              }
          }
      }

  if (!req) { 
    myLogger("req === false");
  } else {

    myLogger("req === true");
  }

  // Use onreadystatechange property
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {

       //myLogger("myLogger - req.onreadystatechange = function(){");

      if(req.readyState == 4) {

          myLogger("myLogger - req.readyState == 4");

          if(req.status === 200) {

            myLogger("myLogger - req.status === 200");

            jsonarry = req.responseText;

            myLogger("myLogger - JSON ARRAY - " + jsonarry);

            myLogger(" ------------- ");

            var identedText = JSON.stringify(jsonarry, null, 4);

            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonarry);

            myLogger("myLogger - Unindented jsonString - " + jsonString);

            var newObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

            myLogger("myLogger - newObject " + newObject);

            myLogger("myLogger - newObject.dummmysetsJSONArr.entryID" + newObject.dummmysetsJSONArr.entryID); 
}

function myLogger(content) {
    if (window.console && window.console.log) {
        console.log("myLogger - " + content);
    }
}
```

Edit: I've reduced my OP code to the by removing the irrelevant bits.

Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: It would help reading and answering if you reduce your code to the relevant parts before posting..

Comment: Since `dummmysetsJSONArr` is an array, shouldn't it be `newObject.dummmysetsJSONArr[0].entryID`

Comment: Yes it should be .. thanks .. I'm new to JS but irrespective I should have realised i need to access the array element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is on this line

```
myLogger("myLogger - newObject.dummmysetsJSONArr.entryID" + newObject.dummmysetsJSONArr.entryID);
```

when you try to log `newObject.dummmysetsJSONArr.entryID`.

Indeed, `newObject.dummmysetsJSONArr.entryID` is undefined since `newObject.dummmysetsJSONArr` is an array.

For example, `newObject.dummmysetsJSONArr[0].entryID` would be valid.